# Did the contextPath is available as a placeHolder for defining the path of a properties files

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Let start with some context:

- Tomcat container
- Autodeploy of war
- No Context.xml in tomcat (at least yet)
- Two (identical) war deploy with two different context (ROOT.war, test.war, why not one war per feature branch)
- Some properties should be different (overwrite) for the two war.

I use something like this for properties:

```
  <bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:internal-common.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:${server.contextPath}/context.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:dev-overwrite.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

The internal-common and the dev-overwrite work as expected.
I can't found the correct placeHolder (not ${server.contextPath} at least) to have an external properties per context.

What I think can't work and are on lot of answer related to this:

- use "env". The two WAR share the same tomcat instance, so the same env
- system properties, same reason
- have different properties name, I don't want as I want the same war
- use the  from tomcat. If I can avoid it, this will simplify my process.
- extend spring properties object will work also, but I wanted to be sure they are nos easier/simplest solution for this.
  Ideally, any placeholder with contextPath information will do the trick.

Comment: You will need support from Spring to do this, the container has no part of this interaction. (I'm not sure if Spring does/does not have such support; I'm just mentioning that the container is not involved.)

Comment: Thanks, spring support seems to be done via stackOverflow. A solution may work with spring with some help from the container. In this case, if I use the Context.xml to set a properties, I can then use it in my spring application. However, because of different reason like the autodeploy I prefer to avoid this one if possible.